# Turn off the Spanselector in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I am trying to turn off the spanselector after using it. When i go to the matplotlib documents, it says about this:

`Set the visible attribute to False if you want to turn off the functionality of the span selector`

But I do not know how to turn off the functionality of span selector like the documentation states.

Here is the code that I have.

```
def disconnect_span(self):
  if self.selection_mode == None:   #This is a variable that i use to call this method
    self.SpanSelector(self.axes, self.onselect, "horizontal", useblit = True,
      rectprops = dict(alpha= 0.5, facecolor = "blue"))
    self.figure_canvas.draw_idle()

 else:
   #Here is where i want to put the disconnect condition
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to toggle the visibility of the `SpanSelector` you will need to use the `set_visible()` method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import SpanSelector

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot([1,2], [3,4])

def onselect(vmin, vmax):
    print vmin, vmax

span = SpanSelector(ax, onselect, 'horizontal')

span.set_visible(False)
```

Here I have created it right after object creation, but you can call the `set_visible()` from anywhere to disable the selector as long you have the `SpanSelector` object.